# How do I use mongoose's .find() to get a user returned by searching for a name or an item in an array that is found in a schema?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to add additional functionality to the user search feature of an existing node.js app, but I am still getting to know node.js, mongoDB and mongoose.  I tired adding an additional index, but it did not work, I think my issue may be with in the .find() function.
I have the following schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    fluentIn: [
        {
            code: String,
            English: String, // English name for the language
        },
    ],
    learning: [
        {
            code: String,
            English: String, // English name for the language
        },
    ]
});

userSchema.index({
    name: "text",
    "fluentIn.English": 1,
});
```

The functionality I want is for the search query to be able to be the name of the user or one the names of one of the languages they are fluent in, and for that user to be returned.
Currently I'm working with the following function within a node.js app:

```
    search(searchQuery, callback) {
        userModel.find(
            { $text: { $search: searchQuery } },
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    callback(result);
                }
            }
        );
    },
```

Comment: "fluentIn.English": 1 change this to "fluentIn.English": "text" in schema.index()

Comment: Thank you! I did that, but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a query that worked. I replaced:

```
{ $text: { $search: searchQuery } }
```

with:

```
{$or:[{name: searchQuery},{"fluentIn.English": searchQuery }]}
```